# Having slight problem with plotting with date in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, date

I am really trying to plot data with date in it. I keep getting an error when I try to compile

```
scrbook: \float@addtolists detected!(scrbook) Implementation of \float@addtolist became(scrbook) deprecated in KOMA-Script v3.01 2008/11/14 and(scrbook) has been replaced by several more flexible(scrbook) features of package `tocbasic`.
```

Now the table I am plotting has 679 lines. I am not so worried about formatting so far, just want to see the plot.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,BCOR=10mm]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
% \usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs}
\usepackage[intoc]{nomencl}
\usepackage{enumerate,color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs,siunitx,varwidth}
\sisetup{detect-all,
    %input-ignore={.},
    group-separator = {.},
    group-minimum-digits=4,
    input-decimal-markers={,}, 
    output-decimal-marker = {,},
    table-alignment-mode=marker,
    table-number-alignment=center,
}
% \usepackage{tablefootnote}

\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
% Packages used for title page layout
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={ }} % to remove the thousand separator
        \begin{axis}[
        width=.8\linewidth,
      height=7cm,
      date coordinates in=x,
      xtick=data,
      xticklabel=\month,
      extra x tick style={xticklabel=\year},
      date ZERO=2015-01-01,
      title=Meðalaflflutningur yfir snið IIIb 2015 til 2023 ásamt spá til 2071,
      xlabel={Dags},
      ylabel={MW},
      legend columns=-1, % to set one line legend
      legend style={at={(0.5,-0.3)},anchor=center}, 
      ymajorgrids
      ]
      \addplot [blue, thick] table [x=Dags, y=Medal, col sep=space] {Flutningur.txt};
      \legend[Flutningur]
        \end{axis}
      \end{tikzpicture}
      \caption{Meðalaflflutningur yfir snið IIIb 2015 til 2023 ásamt spá til 2071  \label{fig:FlutningurIIIb}}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Part of the table in `Flutningur.txt`

```
Dags    Medal   Spá Efri    Neðri
2015-01-01  130.81          
2015-02-01  104.22          
2015-03-01  88.78           
2015-04-01  95.19           
2015-05-01  103.37          
2015-06-01  101.86          
2015-07-01  80.86           
2015-08-01  69.89           
2015-09-01  67.94           
2015-10-01  59.42           
2015-11-01  64.96           
2015-12-01  74.37           
2016-01-01  84.99           
2016-02-01  100.06          
2016-03-01  92.79           
2016-04-01  51.86           
2016-05-01  39.66           
2016-06-01  66.47           
2016-07-01  86.53           
2016-08-01  117.66          
2016-09-01  120.44          
2016-10-01  99.99           
2016-11-01  98.63           
2016-12-01  96.58           
2017-01-01  93.62           
2017-02-01  97.40           
2017-03-01  71.38           
2017-04-01  81.51           
2017-05-01  78.22           
2017-06-01  51.15           
2017-07-01  67.99           
2017-08-01  73.78           
2017-09-01  59.39           
2017-10-01  53.74           
2017-11-01  83.47           
2017-12-01  111.59          
2018-01-01  120.08          
2018-02-01  93.40           
2018-03-01  100.27          
2018-04-01  137.26          
2018-05-01  130.53          
2018-06-01  117.22          
2018-07-01  110.91          
2018-08-01  83.87           
2018-09-01  83.17           
2018-10-01  113.41          
2018-11-01  114.67          
2018-12-01  119.75          
2019-01-01  125.94          
2019-02-01  122.90          
2019-03-01  118.17          
2019-04-01  102.84          
2019-05-01  103.81          
2019-06-01  113.13          
2019-07-01  91.40           
2019-08-01  75.00           
2019-09-01  88.36           
2019-10-01  98.94           
2019-11-01  86.84           
2019-12-01  79.53           
2020-01-01  94.17           
2020-02-01  89.50           
2020-03-01  90.08           
2020-04-01  89.27           
2020-05-01  81.30           
2020-06-01  83.41           
2020-07-01  78.68           
2020-08-01  86.41           
2020-09-01  99.62           
2020-10-01  97.22           
2020-11-01  85.51           
2020-12-01  80.43           
2021-01-01  85.11           
2021-02-01  95.75           
2021-03-01  101.71          
2021-04-01  110.12          
2021-05-01  125.03          
2021-06-01  128.04          
2021-07-01  121.26          
2021-08-01  116.81          
2021-09-01  117.26          
2021-10-01  130.68          
2021-11-01  137.55          
2021-12-01  143.18          
2022-01-01  147.84          
2022-02-01  110.29          
2022-03-01  124.45          
2022-04-01  100.54          
2022-05-01  57.83           
2022-06-01  104.35          
2022-07-01  101.25          
2022-08-01  114.69          
2022-09-01  152.20          
2022-10-01  147.37          
2022-11-01  135.86          
2022-12-01  142.90          
2023-01-01  156.71          
2023-02-01  163.38          
2023-03-01  171.70          
2023-04-01  175.14          
2023-05-01  173.93  173.93  173.93  173.93
2023-06-01      129.15  129.15  129.15
2023-07-01      129.68  129.90  129.40
2023-08-01      130.22  130.65  129.65
2023-09-01      130.76  131.40  129.90
2023-10-01      131.29  132.15  130.15
```

In my `.txt` the columns aren't shifted at the bottom.

I am perfectly happy with seeing the x axis with this format (or any format that makes sense).

[image]

I am not very experienced with pgfplot, and I am not the strongest coder there as well so any idea in how to get this going would be really appreciated. The quality difference between pgfplots and excel plot is significant, and I would much prefer pgfplots.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you load `color` but then also `xcolor`. Also, `pgfplotstable` loads `pgfplots` and `pgfplots` loads `tikz`. So, I would suggest that you try to clean up the preamble a bit. What is missing, however, is  `\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}`, since this is needed for the option `date ZERO`. And you should replace `\legend[Flutningur]` by `\addlegendentry{Flutningur}`.

Comment: I don't get the error you mention, however. Is your TeX installation up to date?

Comment: @JasperHabicht I tried cleaning the preable, then I added `usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}` and ran this again, but I still get the same error. Not finding out why. I am running Arch Linux install, so I am pretty sure my Tex installation is up to date.

Comment: Seems like I made a mistake with `\addlegendentry` I used regular braces instead of curly braces. Things are compiling at the moment

Comment: The error you show really looks like something else is also not quite right in your code. But I don't get any error referring to `scrbook`, so I cannot reproduce this problem.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thank you for your help anyway. Just my curiosity, I can also plot the next columns (which start well in the table) just by calling new `\addplot`, right?

Comment: Yeah, things are not very right with this plot. Have no idea where my error is lying

Comment: Well, theoretically, you can just add the other columns from the data using `\addplot`. But your table data is not formatted in an optimal way: A lot of values seem to be missing and I wonder whether "Spá Efir" is supposed to be one single column title (which would not work, due to the space). You might want to use a comma as column separator, which will make it easier for PGFPlots to parse the data.

Comment: No, Spá is prediction, Efri is basically upper boundry and Neðri is lower bound of the prediction. So these three columns don't start showing until the measured data is finished. I'll try to change this to comma separated data.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I put quite lot of work into making the `txt` file comma separated, and that will just not run at all. Even with the original code. I always get the same error code as presented in the post. I have to admit, this is beyond my understanding.

Comment: As for the `scrbook` error, as I said, I am unable to reproduce it and hence cannot tell you a solution currently. Did you test on another machine or on Overleaf as well? Does the minimal working example you provided also issue this error for you? This error seems unrelated to PGFplots actually, but I could imagine that it has to do with another incompatible package. I would suggest that you try to isolate this error by commenting out as many parts of your document as needed to solve the problem.